# Should I use "prosthetics" or "prostheses" for a plural noun?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, nouns

Just looking around Google, it appears that "prosthetics" as a plural noun is used in non-technical marketing literature, while "prostheses" is used in technical journals. Is there any difference in meaning?

I already know that "prosthetic" is supposed to be an adjective, but I see it used often as a noun. Is that incorrect?

Comment: What are you using for the singular noun???

Comment: sometimes "prosthetic" and sometimes "prosthesis".  not consistent.

Comment: Use the plural of the word you would have used the singular of.

Comment: Try using a dictionary rather than Google - altho' an online dictionary would be acceptable.  If the dictionary doesn't answer the question, then provide the details & explain why.

Comment: Did you medical dictionary not tell you prostheses describes multiple items and prosthetics describes the science to which they belong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a distinction between the noun *prosthesis* and the noun *prosthetic,* or their plural forms *prostheses* and *prosthetics,* when used to mean "artificial body parts." They are synonyms, like *dyslexic* and *dyslectic.* *Prosthetic(s)* is listed in the Oxford English Dictionary with this meaning, with several citations from medical or surgical sources, so I don't see any grounds for considering this usage non-technical or incorrect. Perhaps it could be viewed as an abbreviation of "prosthetic device(s)".

As you've mentioned, these words can also be used in some other ways, and they are not always synonyms in those other senses. Only *prosthetic* can serve as an adjective. When used as a noun referring to the general field, it seems that *prosthetics* is used with the suffix *-s* (analogous to nouns like *physics, obstetrics*), while *prosthesis* is used in its singular form (analogous to nouns like *synthesis*).

---

Even though they evidently can be used as synonyms, some people do seem to distinguish the meanings of the words; I ran across an example in the following question from the Hinduism Stack Exchange: [Artificial Limb Transplant ( Prothesis) in Rig-Veda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21672/artificial-limb-transplant-prothesis-in-rig-veda)

> In medicine, a  Prosthesis , is an artificial device that replaces a missing body part lost through trauma, disease, or congenital conditions. prosthetics is simply replacement of missing limbs.

I don't know of course what the original poster's background is, but I think this is evidence showing that some people share your impression about the difference between the two words.

Answer (score 2):

As someone currently working with prostheses, the professional accepted use is prosthesis is the noun and prosthetic is only used as an adjective. However, colloquially both are understood.

Comment: The language is probably changing as fast as the sophistication of the devices these days.